# Storing KnockoutJS variable value in Razor view variable

Tags: razor, knockout.js

I am trying to store a Knockout variable's value in Razor server side code. Something like this

```
@{
  String test = KNOCK_OUT_VARIABLE;
}
```

in a `.cshtml` file.

Comment: you can't . `ko` is client side where razor is server side . ko variables i interpret those are observables which are local to vm you cannot use them in your razor but you can do opposite .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible / you're looking at this the wrong way.

You're confused about [the differences / border / gap / relation between server side and client side programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) (see also [this PHP version of a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/419956)). To get Knockout values (client side) to your Razor and/or Controllers you need to `GET` or `POST` something, including the client side value in your request.

You should probably read up on how client and server interaction work in general, and/or follow some tutorials. The [Knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) are pretty good and have [a relevant tutorial about loading/saving data](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving).